# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "nvarchar". Необходимо объявить скалярную переменную "@Статус"."

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE Табель SET  Статус = @Статус, [Код смены] = @[Код смены], [Время входа] = @[Время входа], [Время выхода] = @[Время выхода]  WHERE [Код сотрудника] = @[Код сотрудника] AND Дата = @Дата AND [Код табеля] = @[Код табеля]", connectionString);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("[Код табеля]", textBox5.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("[Код сотрудника]", код_сотрудникаTextBox.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Дата", датаDateTimePicker.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Статус", comboBox1.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("[Код смены]", comboBox2.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("[Время входа]", время_входаTextBox.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("[Время выхода]", время_входаTextBox.Text);
command.Connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
command.Connection.Close();
```

При выполнении запроса возникает ошибка:

> Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "nvarchar". Необходимо объявить скалярную переменную "@Статус".

Answer (score 3):

Цитата из документации [Database Identifiers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver16):

> Rules for Regular Identifiers
>
> 4. Embedded spaces or special characters are not allowed.

В именах параметров не разрешены пробелы.
Уберём из них пробелы и квадратные скобки.

Попутно исправим другие ошибки и недочёты: имя соединения (у вас оно почему-то названо `connectionString`), опасность потери ресурсов (используем `using` для устранения этого), использование устаревшего и опасного метода `AddWithValue` (заменим его на `Add` с указанием точного типа).

Кроме того, `время_входаTextBox` используется дважды. Будьте внимательны!

```
string sql = @"UPDATE Табель SET Статус = @Статус, [Код смены] = @КодСмены, [Время входа] = @ВремяВхода, [Время выхода] = @ВремяВыхода WHERE [Код сотрудника] = @КодСотрудника AND Дата = @Дата AND [Код табеля] = @КодТабеля";

using var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
connection.Open();

using var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

command.Parameters.Add("КодТабеля", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox5.Text; // int.Parse(textBox5.Text)
command.Parameters.Add("КодСотрудника", SqlDbType.Int).Value = код_сотрудникаTextBox.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("Дата", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = датаDateTimePicker.Value;
command.Parameters.Add("Статус", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = comboBox1.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("КодСмены", SqlDbType.Int).Value = comboBox2.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("ВремяВхода", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = время_входаTextBox.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("ВремяВыхода", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = время_выходаTextBox.Text;

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Благодаря использованию `using` соединение будет гарантировано закрыто, даже в случае возникновения исключения. Вызывать метод `Close()` не нужно.

Я не знаю, какие именно типы используются у вас в таблице, поэтому сами укажите правильные типы `SqlDbType`. При необходимости примените `int.Parse` и тому подобные методы. А лучше используйте `NumericUpDown` для ввода чисел вместо `TextBox`.

Почему не стоит использовать метод `AddWithValue`:
[Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)
[AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html)
[AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)
Достаточно прочитать любую из этих статей.

Comment: command.Parameters.Add("Статус", SqlDbType.NVarChar) = comboBox1.Text;
Левая часть выражения назначения должна быть переменной, свойством или индексатором

Comment: Я просто новичок и из за этого мб вопрос глупый, но все же я не знаю как решить эту проблему

Comment: @FoleEG - я поправил опечатку. Было пропущено `.Value`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Для типа SqlDbType.NVarChar весьма желательно указывать размерность.

Answer (score 1):

В [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=netframework-4.7) в примере в вызове `AddWithValue` название переменной используется с собачкой, так же как оно выглядит в строке с `SQL` кодом, так что попробуйте сделать так же:

```cs
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Код табеля]", textBox5.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Код сотрудника]", код_сотрудникаTextBox.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Дата", датаDateTimePicker.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Статус", comboBox1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Код смены]", comboBox2.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Время входа]", время_входаTextBox.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Время выхода]", время_входаTextBox.Text);
```

Comment: Нет, собачка в методах `Add*` не важна.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Для любой версии фреймворка? И оно само тогда `@` добавляет к именам подставляемых переменных или что происходит? Просто по-другому что-то не знаю как тогда происходящее объяснить. Может я и не прав, конечно, но попробовать не мешало бы.